# Cómo insertar un 'NULL' en MySQL desde mi insert PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

por favor me podrían ayudar con este problema, ya se que se repitió la pregunta pero e probado con las respuestas de los demás y no me funciona no se cual sea el error. O si por lo menos me ayudaran a identificarlo. Gracias.

Aclaro que mi campo id_carrera puede tener valores NULL, y en mi Base de datos permite null ya que este aguarda el id de la carrera del alumno.

```
    <?php

    $matricula = $_POST['matricula_1'] ;
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre_1'] ;
    $apellido_pa = $_POST['apellido_pa_1'] ;
    $apellido_ma = $_POST['apellido_ma_1'] ;

    if($_POST['id_carrera']!=null){
        $id_carrera = $_POST['id_carrera'] ;
    }else{
        $id_carrera = null;
    }

    //Elimina los espacios en blanco de inicio y final
    $nombre = trim($nombre , " ");
    $apellido_pa = trim($apellido_pa , " ");
    $apellido_ma = trim($apellido_ma , " ");

    //Deja solo un espacio en blanco entre palabras
    $nombre  = preg_replace( "([ ]+)"," ",$nombre);
    $apellido_pa  = preg_replace( "([ ]+)"," ",$apellido_pa);
    $apellido_ma  = preg_replace( "([ ]+)"," ",$apellido_ma);

    //Cuenta la cantidad de caracteres
    //echo strlen($nombre);


    include_once('Conexion/Abrir_Conexion.php');

    $con = "insert into alumno (matricula, nombre, apellido_pa, apellido_ma, id_carrera) values ('$matricula', '$nombre', '$apellido_pa', '$apellido_ma', '$id_carrera')";

    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $con);

    include_once('Conexion/Cerrar_Conexion.php');

    if (!$consulta){
        echo "No se almacenó el registro en la BD";
    }

?>
```

Y así esta mi HTML

```html
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="id_carrera" id="id_carrera">
       <option value="">Seleccione su carrera </option>
         <?php
         while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {  
                ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $registro[0] ; ?>"> 
                 <?php echo $registro[1]; ?> 
       </option>
                <?php
                     }
                ?>
</select>
```

En mi BD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. Por un lado muestras una consulta de inserción que nunca ejecutas. Y por otro lado muestras un HTML  con un `select` que parece llenarse con datos de la base de datos.   ¿Cuál es el problema y qué es lo que hace tu código en sí?

Comment: Haciendo supuestos, creo que cuando intentas insertar en tu BD el valor de `id_carrera` te llega como un valor vacío, y al no tener un control de excepciones sobre la consulta que estas realizando no te arroja el error. Aunque, es posible que no sea asi, en caso tal de que si lleguen los demas datos a tu BD, así que lo mejor es que nos proporciones mayor información para llegar a una posible solución.

Comment: Amigo te pongo el código completo espera, intento que en mi BD de MySQL quede cómo null cuando el alumno no seleccione ninguna carrera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a mostrar un estilo que a mi me gusta implementar y además daremos seguridad al código, ya que como tienes tu consulta ahora mismo es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.

La técnica consiste en recoger los valores del POST mediante un *operador ternario*. Cuando no haya datos en el POST podemos asignar `NULL`, una cadena vacía, o lo que fuera. En este caso asignaremos siempre `NULL` cuando no haya datos. Además esto sirve para parar la consulta cuando ciertas columnas *esenciales* sean nulas.

El código sería así:

```
$arrResult=array();  //Variable utilitaria para informar sobre el estado del código
$matricula   = (!empty($_POST['matricula_1']))   ?  $_POST['matricula_1']   : NULL ;
$nombre      = (!empty($_POST['nombre_1']))      ?  $_POST['nombre_1']      : NULL ;
$apellido_pa = (!empty($_POST['apellido_pa_1'])) ?  $_POST['apellido_pa_1'] : NULL ;
$apellido_ma = (!empty($_POST['apellido_ma_1'])) ?  $_POST['apellido_ma_1'] : NULL ;
$id_carrera =  (!empty($_POST['id_carrera']))    ?  $_POST['id_carrera']    : NULL ;
include_once('Conexion/Abrir_Conexion.php');

$sql = "INSERT INTO alumno 
            (
                matricula, 
                nombre, 
                apellido_pa, 
                apellido_ma, 
                id_carrera
            ) 
            VALUES 
            (   ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?
            )";
$stmt=$conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("isssi",$matricula,$nombre,$apellido_pa,$apellido_ma, $id_carrera);
if ($stmt->execute()){
    /*Esto es sólo un gadget :) */
    $totalInsert=$stmt->affected_rows;  
    $mensaje=($totalInsert > 0) ? "Se ha insertado correctamente" : "No fue posible la inserción. Error: ".$stmt->error;  
    $arrResult['mensaje'] = $mensaje;
}else{
    $arrResult['error'] = "No fue posible la inserción. Error:  ".$conexion->error;
}

$conexion->close();
print_r($arrResult);
```

Comment: Amigo Tu respuesta es muy efectiva Recomiendo esta. Gracias por tu tiempo :) Hasta luego.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos problemas.  En primer lugar la variable `$_POST['id_carrera']` nunca va a ser null porque inclusive si la dejas vacia, el valor va a ser de una cadena vacia.  En segundo lugar, para chequear si una variable es o no `null`, no puedes usar `==` o `!=`.  Intentalo de esta forma:

```
$matricula = $_POST['matricula_1'] ;
$nombre = $_POST['nombre_1'] ;
$apellido_pa = $_POST['apellido_pa_1'] ;
$apellido_ma = $_POST['apellido_ma_1'] ;

if (isset($_POST['id_carrera'])){
    $id_carrera = $_POST['id_carrera'] ;
}else{
    $id_carrera = NULL;
}

$con = "insert into alumno (matricula, nombre, apellido_pa, apellido_ma, id_carrera) 
           values ('$matricula', '$nombre', '$apellido_pa', '$apellido_ma',
           " . (isset($id_carrera) ? "'$id_carrera'" : "NULL") . ")";
```

Comment: Ok amigo e incluso esto ya lo intente y no funciono: 
                                                                                 
     if(empty($_POST['dato'])){
   $dato=null; 
}
else{
   $dato=$_POST['dato'];
}

Comment: Es por como tienes el insert.  Intentalo como esta en mi respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo amigo pero ese insert solo funcionaria cuando no se selecciona una carrera pero cuando haya selecciona una carrera supongo que voy a tener que poner mi insert normal. Y eso no  es optimo ya que yo quería usar un solo insert cual sea la ocasión de si hay datos o no. Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Ya probaste mi codigo en los dos casos? Cuando no seleccionas carrera y cuando si?

Comment: Mis respetos amigo, funciono perdón por la tardanza, ejeje Gracias. :)

Comment: De nada @DiegosSánchez, solo dos cosas mas.  Primero, quizas te interese este post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php  para que aprendas sobre la inyeccion de `SQL`.  Segundo, veo que has hecho ya varias preguntas, pero no has marcado ninguna respuesta como correcta.  Es una buena practica aceptar las respuestas que te han ayudado para que la comunidad te siga ayudando.

Comment: Lo siento amigo pero cómo soy nuevo en esta comunidad recientemente me registre y aún no se cómo se maneja esta pagina.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80128/discussion-between-alanfcm-and-diegos-sanchez).

Answer (score -1):

Con

```
$id_carrera = 'NULL';
```

tendrás el `NULL VALUE` asignado a tu atributo en la base de datos (siempre y cuando el atributo sea numérico claro)